# DSU/CSU cards seem to fail too often

Tags: networking, cisco, router

I help maintain a network with over 40 locations, each one with a leased T1 line connected via a Cisco 1841 router with an integrated T1 DSU/CSU card. The routers are very reliable but occasionally the T1 card will fail, whereas we then have to overnight a new T1 card to the location. I understand the T1 card is the first point of contact with the outside world (lightning, power outage from our service provider could damage the card).

My question is this: should these T1 cards be failing so easily when the rest of the router is completely fine each time?

Comment: I always preferred external CSU / DSU.  What does Cisco say?

Comment: Who determines that it fails? Define 'occasionally'. What model WIC is this?

Comment: How can you replace an integrated card?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, your T1/DS1 WIC should not be failing "so easily."  [While just about all (I am not a Ph.D EE so I cannot confidently say "all") semiconductors experience degradation, decay, and aging -- mostly in the dielectric](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/hardware/transistor-aging/0), top-end ASIC and device manufacturers (read: Cisco's enterprise lines) have very high safety margins and lifetimes.

If you are going through T1/DS1 WIC's "so easily" I would look to other causes.  See below.

***Background -- Skip Ahead if you like***

It is rather rare that your DS1 comes off the street and goes straight into your WIC.  Generally, the incumbent local exchange carrier (ILEC) (read: last mile copper owner) will terminate your DS1 to a "smart jack" in a shelf (metal box with cards in it).  This "smart jack" serves as the physical point of demarcation for the DS1.  It can be used to isolate facilities/provider problems from customer premises equipment (CPE) problems.

Most modern metropolitan T1/DS1 circuits are delivered from the central office (CO) to the smart jack as HDSL2/4 -- riding on a single pair.  At the smart jack the HDSL turns into traditional B8ZS, ESF two pair DS1 (there are variations).  HDSL line voltage can (but shouldn't) approach 200VDC.  Traditional T1/DS1 is generally under 3.3VDC.  Quite a difference.

***If you skipped ahead -- start here***

[Make sure that the shelf in which the smart jacks live is properly grounded with minimum 6AWG wire.](http://www.rayvaughan.com/t1_problems.htm)  If the shelf has been there a while -- in a high traffic communal telco room there exists the possibility of the grounding wire being bumped or removed.

The smart jacks can build up a lot of extra charge and if there is not a proper ground on the smart jack/shelf it can either damage the smart jack itself or the T1/DS1 WIC behind it.

I have been witness to a handful of smart jacks and T1/DS1 Cisco WIC's failing several times on account of improper grounding of the smart jack/shelf.